# In case of logistic regression, how should I interpret this learning curve between cost and number of examples?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have obtained the following learning curve on plotting the learning curves for training and cross validation sets between the error cost, and number of training examples (in 100s in the graph). Can someone please tell me if this learning curve is ever possible? Because I am of the impression that the Cross validation error should decrease as the number of training examples increase.

[Learning Curve. Note that the x axis denotes the number of training examples in 100s.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3DrS.png)

EDIT :

This is the code which I use to calculate the 9 values for plotting the learning curves. 
X is the 2D matrix of the training set examples. It is of dimensions `m x (n+1)`. y is of dimensions `m x 1`, and each element has value 1 or 0.

```
  for j=1:9
    disp(j)
    [theta,J] = trainClassifier(X(1:(j*100),:),y(1:(j*100)),lambda);
    [error_train(j), grad] = costprediciton_train(theta , X(1:(j*100),:), y(1:(j*100)));
    [error_cv(j), grad] = costfunction_test2(theta , Xcv(1:(j*100),:),ycv(1:(j*100)));
  end
```

The code I use for finding the optimal value of Theta from the training set.

```
% Train the classifer. Return theta
function [optTheta, J] = trainClassifier(X,y,lambda)
  [m,n]=size(X);
  initialTheta = zeros(n, 1);
  options=optimset('GradObj','on','MaxIter',100);
  [optTheta, J, Exit_flag ] = fminunc(@(t)(regularizedCostFunction(t, X, y, lambda)), initialTheta, options);
end


%regularized cost

function [J, grad] = regularizedCostFunction(theta, X, y,lambda)
  [m,n]=size(X);
  h=sigmoid( X * theta);
  temp1 = -1 * (y .* log(h));
  temp2 = (1 - y) .* log(1 - h);
  thetaT = theta;
  thetaT(1) = 0;
  correction = sum(thetaT .^ 2) * (lambda / (2 * m));
  J = sum(temp1 - temp2) / m + correction;
  grad = (X' * (h - y)) * (1/m) + thetaT * (lambda / m);
end
```

The code I use for calculating the error cost for prediction of results for training set: (similar is the code for error cost of CV set)
Theta is of dimensions `(n+1) x 1` and consists of the coefficients of the features in the hypothesis function.

```
function [J,grad] = costprediciton_train(theta , X, y)
  [m,n]=size(X);
  h=sigmoid(X * theta);
  temp1 = y .* log(h);
  temp2 = (1-y) .* log(1- h);
  J = -sum (temp1 + temp2)/m;
  t=h-y;
  grad=(X'*t)*(1/m);

end

function [J,grad] = costfunction_test2(theta , X, y)

  m= length(y);
  h=sigmoid(X*theta);
  temp1 = y .* log(h);
  temp2 = (1-y) .* log(1- h);
  J = -sum (temp1 + temp2)/m ;
  grad = (X' * (h - y)) * (1/m) ;

end
```

The Sigmoid function:

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
  g= zeros(size(z));
  den=1 + exp(-1*z);
  g = 1 ./ den;
end
```

Comment: you did not specify what is the exact setting - what is the test set? Is there N points, and during CV you use x for training and N-x for testing, N/x times? If so - the curve is impossible and you have some errors. However if your setting is somehow peculiar (testing on some weird set of points) then everything is possible.

Comment: I have a total of 2700 examples for Training, and 900 for CV. On every value `x1` marked on the x axis, I use the first  `100*x1` examples from both of them

Comment: Then this is quite peculiar setting. If you have a predefined test set you should not use CV (in your case test set is actually changing with x, thus these values are not comparable), but simply report error on test set. Now, given that both test set and train come from the same underlying distribution through iid sampling - your error should decrease over time. One more missing thing is what is your "error" here (scale of y is weird, is this the number of incorrect classifications * 100?)

Comment: I've been following Andrew Ng's course on ML, and he defined the error on the y axis as average error per example. Moreover, he uses this same method for plotting the learning curves. 
Can you please explain how I should go about iid sampling? It is completely new to me.

Comment: IID sampling is rather an underlying statistical assumption, nearly impossible to test in practice (unless you use toy data generated by yourself). You should provide your code in order to get more precise answers, I would say there is 90% chance that you have bugs there.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention this earlier, but he defines the average error using a log(sigmoid). I'm editing the question details to include the main part of the code.

Comment: you are still missing def of `costfunction_test2`

Comment: Added all the functions now